# Rotate among Forms to display URLs at intervals

Tags: vb.net, vbscript

New to programming and trying to teach self, so please be patient..:)  I am trying to create an application for display purposes that will consist of 4 forms each displaying a different webpage.  They should rotate at 20 second intervals on form 5 as the display.  I found some code on this site that looks like (with my limited knowledge) work, but I cannot seem to get it to go.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
Public Class Form5

Shared counter As Integer = 1
Private Shared Sub StartRotating()
    Dim myTimer As New System.Windows.Forms.Timer()
    myTimer.Interval = 20000
    ' 20 seconds 
    AddHandler myTimer.Tick, New EventHandler(AddressOf TimerEventProcessor)
    myTimer.Start()
End Sub

Private Shared Sub TimerEventProcessor(ByVal myObject As [Object], ByVal myEventArgs As EventArgs)

    If counter = 1 Then
        Form1.BringToFront()
    End If
    If counter = 2 Then
        form2.BringToFront()
    End If
    If counter = 3 Then
        form3.BringToFront()
    End If
    If counter = 4 Then
        form4.BringToFront()
        'reset counter
        counter = 0
    End If
    counter += 1
End Sub


End Class
```

I am also open to other ideas such as simply rotating URLs on a Timer if that is possible.

Comment: heres an idea: why not ONE form and simply rotate the URL displayed from a list of them when the timer goes off?  One form per URL is a lot of resources.

Comment: TBH mostly because I didn't know you could do that.  I was searching for a solution when I found the c# version of the code above on this site for someone trying to do a very similar thing.  Guess I am starting over...:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you started rotating thru a List of URLs instead of some forms (as per comments). Form level declarations:

```
Private urlList As List(of String)        ' storage
Private thisUrl As Integer = 0
```

In form Load:

```
urlList = New List(of String)          ' instance created
urlList.Add("stackoverflow.com")       ' add a url
...etc
```

In Timer tick

```
If thisUrl >= List.Count Then
    thisUrl = 0                        ' rotate
End If

myBrowserCtl.Url = New Uri(urlList(thisUrl ))
thisUrl + =1

Me.BringToFront
```